# chrome extension - change authentication

Tags: google-chrome-extension, proxy

I am using chrome extension API to develop an extension that allows to switch proxies.

When using proxies that have different authentication but the same host and port, I get the same IP.

When a user change the proxy I call `chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: 'regular'})` and `chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(authcb, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}, ['blocking']);`

I tried to unset the authentication listener using `chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(authcb, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}, ['blocking']);` , setting the authentication manually using `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener` , and using dynamic rule to add the authorization header, but none of these seem to work, I still get the same IP. Note: trying to set the authorization header manually makes chrome prompt for authorization.

Note: testing the proxies with `curl` gives the expected result: different IPs for different authentications.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/77010780/17346799 .

Chrome seems to not have a full coverage for this point (handling authentication).